# How to fix 'When I write the stored procedure for searching'?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure for searching in many records and nothing wrong but the problem is when I search for a record and need to update this record after search gave me this exception and when I go to record without search I can update it. Is this a problem in C# or in the stored procedure?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm.dtpCheck.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
 frm.dtpnextCheck.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtIncomMoney.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtResMoney.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtfrom.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtto.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        frm.Text = "Update Patient" + this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        frm.btnOk.Text = "Update";

ALTER proc [dbo].[Search_Pa]
@ID nvarchar(50)
as
select * from tb_Patients
inner join tb_Rolls
on tb_Patients.RollID =tb_Rolls.RollID
where tb_Patients.PatientName+
tb_Patients.PatientAddress+
tb_Patients.PatientPhone
like '%'+@ID+'%'    


    param[7] = new SqlParameter("@dateofcheck", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
        param[7].Value = DateOfCheck;
        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@dateofnextcheck", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
        param[8].Value = DateOfNextCheck;
        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@residualmoney", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[9].Value = ResidualMoney;
        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@receivemoney", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[10].Value = IncomingMoney;
        param[11] = new SqlParameter("@firstcheck", SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
        param[11].Value = FirstCeck;
        param[12] = new SqlParameter("@endcheck", SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
        param[12].Value = EndCheck;
        param[13] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[13].Value = ID;
        param[14] = new SqlParameter("@RID", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[14].Value = RID;

        dal.IUD("update_Patients", param);
        dal.CloseCon();
    }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)  in Cells[9]

Comment: Not a single line of code that you showed has anything to do with calling a Stored Procedure. How are we supposed to fix what we can not see?

Comment: Sorry I have a mistake on the number of cells the exception pointed on cell [9]

Comment: If you're using a datetime picker, how can you end up with an invalid string for a datetime?

Comment: Code relevant to the question should be in the question, not the comments, @Anas.

Comment: That "FormatException" is a .Net message, not a SQL message. So this error is in your C# code. Apparently you are trying to create a DateTime value out of a string (not shown in your current code). What *is* that string value? How are you trying to convert it to a DateTime? Please [edit] these details into your question.

Comment: I can't see how that C# code, and that query are related. Also, you should be using an `OR` statement to check if any of those columns contain the value you are looking for, not concatenating them all.

Comment: this is how the code looks like and down is the store proc